# Как переместить текстовый курсор в Text

Tags: python, tkinter

Мне нужно переместить курсор на определенный символ с помощью кода. У меня есть текстовый виджет в котором пользователь набирает текст, мне нужно, чтобы курсор пользователя переместился допустим на 3 символ
Вот, что у меня есть:

```
inputText = Text()
inputText.insert(1.0, "Hello, world!")
inputText.pack()
```

Мне нужно, чтобы код переместил текстовый курсор на символ l, это возможно?

Comment: Поищи ANSI Escape codes, с ними можно перемещать курсор. Вроде бы есть библиотеки обертки для данных кодов.

Comment: [Пример здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27612978/8489602) можешь посмотреть

Comment: @DiMithras ANSI коды работают в терминале (не в каждом), но не в виджетах графического интерфейса.

Comment: @insolor тег пропустил, пардоньте‥

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import tkinter as tk

...

# Установить курсор в первой строке перед символом с индексом 3
# (или после 3-го символа, если считать с 1)
# В вашей строке - получится между двумя буквами l в слове Hello
inputText.mark_set(tk.INSERT, "1.3")

# Переместить фокус ввода в текстовое поле
# (если фокус не в текстовом поле, то мы не увидим, что курсор поменял положение)
inputText.focus()
```

Чтобы выделить текст, нужно создать тег `tk.SEL` с нужными границами:

```
inputText.tag_add(tk.SEL, "1.7", "1.12")  # Выделяем слово "world"
inputText.mark_set(tk.INSERT, "1.12")  # Ставим курсор в конце выделения
inputText.focus()
```

Если нужно выделить весь текст:

```
inputText.tag_add(tk.SEL, "1.0", tk.END)
```

Comment: А есть возможность через mark_set выделить слово?

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо большое